# Drivers for dwa-171 wifi usb dongle

Tags: usb, wifi, driver, cross-compilation

I'm having trouble to compile and use drivers for dwa-171 wifi usb.
I have tried a lot of things but currently i'm unable to load module.

Recap of what i have done so far:

```
Getting kernel sources:
  mkdir src && cd src
  git clone --depth 500 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git
  git clone --depth 15 https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware.git
Link sources:
  sudo ln -s /home/pi/src/linux /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build
  sudo ln -s /home/pi/src/linux/arch/arm /home/pi/src/linux/arch/armv6l
Preparing to compile modules
  make mrproper && make menuconfig && make modules_prepare
  cp ../firmware/extra/Module.symvers .
Get drivers and compile
  git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au
  cd rtl8812au/
  *edit Makefile for raspberry*
  make clean && make && make install
Insert fresh module
  insmod 8812au.ko
```

Which return me:
Error: could not insert module 8812au.ko: Invalid module format

I haven't made much more progress, trying different stuff without success.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

#### EDIT:

Solved, somes errors where mades when creating kernel config file.
Copying current config and recompile does the job.

```
zcat /proc/config.gz > ./.config
```

Comment: Does this USB dongle explicitly require a driver? Most of them will work right out of the box. All you have to do is edit a network entry in `wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Comment: @JamesTaylor It does require 8812au driver which is not in the rpi out of the box modules.

Comment: Followed "Recap of what i have done so far" on a Pi 2 model B. Cannot make for some reason. Anyone else run into this? 
`sudo make
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.18.7-v7+/build M=/opt/rtl8812au modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/lib/modules/3.18.7-v7+/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'modules'. Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/lib/modules/3.18.7-v7+/build'
Makefile:1051: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2`

Comment: **Near duplicate:** http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/28307/5538

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrying from scratch did the job. Main error was the kernel config file. So copying current raspbian running config file correct this.

Here is the full list of command to compile the drivers.

1. Get a fresh raspbian, use `raspi-config` to expand disk and allow maximum ram (16 or 32 only to gpu), then reboot.
2. Update and install dependancies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   sudo apt-get install  build-essential bc libncurses5-dev
   ```
3. Clone raspberry linux kernel. (make some tea)

   ```
   git clone http://github.com/raspberrypi/linux rpi-kernel
   cd rpi-kernel
   ```

   You may want to dl only your desired version

   ```
   # replace 3.12 to the one you want, see uname -r to current
   wget -c https://codeload.github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tar.gz/rpi-3.12.y
   tar xavf rpi-3.2.y
   rm rpi-3.2.y
   cd linux-rpi-3.12.y
   ```
4. Copy **or** Create config file

   - Copy from current config

     ```
     zcat /proc/config.gz > ./.config
     ```
   - Create new one

     ```
     make bcmrpi_defconfig
     ```
5. (Optionnal) If you want to tune in some features: `make menuconfig`.
6. Build kernel: `make` (Very long (about 7h), maybe use cross compile or go to bed)
7. Build and install modules: `make modules_install`
8. Set up for building external modules: `make modules_prepare`
9. Install headers: `sudo make headers_install`
10. Install kernel: `sudo make zinstall` then reboot (you can look uname -a before and after to ensure kernel is installed)
11. Get driver sources (from *gnab*'s modified version because it include config for rpi)

    ```
    git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au
    cd rtl8812au
    nano Makefile # <-- pick RPI platform and disable others
    ```
12. Build module: `make` (Time to make tea again)
13. Install module: `sudo make install`
14. Load module: `modprobe 8812au`
15. Your usb dongle should work and an interface should be shown in `iwconfig`

You should now have drank two cup of tea, a nice night of sleep and a working driver for your wifi dongle

Comment: first thank you for the instruction, but I'm facing a challenge as well on step 12. When I tried make, I get this error; `make make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.18.7-v7+/build M=/home/pi/rtl8812au modules make[1]: *** /lib/modules/3.18.7-v7+/build: No such file or directory. Stop. Makefile:1051: recipe for target 'modules' failed make: *** [modules] Error 2` Please advise and thank you in advance.

Comment: It was a long, i remember having your error but cant recall what i did to solved it. My thought would be, check your kernel sources and makefile options.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is actually [the same answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28307/dwa-171-using-8812au-ko-does-not-seem-to-work-on-linux-kernel-version-3-18-8/55700#55700) I gave to the problem described in [DWA-171 using 8812au.ko does not seem to work on Linux kernel version 3.18.8+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28307/dwa-171-using-8812au-ko-does-not-seem-to-work-on-linux-kernel-version-3-18-8).

I recently stumbled upon similar problems when I was trying to find a driver for my [Edimax EW-7811UTC](http://us.edimax.com/edimax/merchandise/merchandise_detail/data/edimax/us/wireless_adapters_ac600_dual-band/ew-7811utc/) which uses the same chipset as the [D-Link DWA-171](http://www.dlink.com/no/nb/home-solutions/connect/adapters/dwa-171-wireless-ac-dual-band-usb-adapter). I had to realize that while [OpenELEC](http://openelec.tv/) for instance does come with a driver for the [Edimax EW-7811UTC](http://us.edimax.com/edimax/merchandise/merchandise_detail/data/edimax/us/wireless_adapters_ac600_dual-band/ew-7811utc/) out of the box, [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) doesn’t.

I found a small tool called [rpi-source](https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/wiki) that is able to install the kernel sources used to build the kernel on your [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) image. It's supposed to work for Raspberry Pis 1 and 2 and kernels starting from version 3.10.37.

I've tested following procedure to compile and install the [rtl8812au](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au) driver on a [Raspberry Pi 2 Model B](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-2-model-b/) running [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) in different versions:

- Raspbian Jessie release 2016-05-27 using kernel version 4.4.11-v7+
- Raspbian Jessie release 2016-09-23 using kernel version 4.4.21-v7+

```sh
# install necessary software
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bc git

# download raspbian kernel sources, takes some minutes
sudo wget "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/notro/rpi-source/master/rpi-source" -O /usr/bin/rpi-source
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/rpi-source
rpi-source

# download the rtl8812au kernel driver and compile it, takes some minutes
git clone "https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au"
cd rtl8812au
sed -i 's/CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = y/CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = n/g' Makefile
sed -i 's/CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI = n/CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI = y/g' Makefile
make
# copy the driver and use it
sudo cp 8812au.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/wireless
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe 8812au

# check wlan0 interface appeared
ifconfig
iwconfig
```

I also created an [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/index.html) role called [raspbian-rtl8812au](https://github.com/layereight/raspbian-rtl8812au) you can use to automate the driver setup in an [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/index.html) playbook.