# DWA-171 using 8812au.ko does not seem to work on Linux kernel version 3.18.8+

Tags: wifi, driver, realtek

I have already tried the procedure described in ([Drivers for dwa-171 wifi usb dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26302/drivers-for-dwa-171-wifi-usb-dongle/28300?noredirect=1#comment35908_28300)) on several RPi's without success. Each attempt fails at the end of the process with "ERROR: could not insert '8812au': Exec format error".

My Linux kernel version is:

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.8+ #763 PREEMPT Sat Feb 28 18:24:36 GMT 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

readelf -h on the module gives:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              REL (Relocatable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x0
  Start of program headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          991408 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000000, Version5 EABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           0 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         0
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         37
  Section header string table index: 34
```

modinfo gives:

```
filename:       /home/pi/rtl8812au/8812au.ko
version:        v4.2.2_7502.20130517
author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
license:        GPL
srcversion:     3424792CB6F8055CE7AE336
```

The last line in dmesg says:

```
8812au: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
```

Any help to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Near duplicate:** http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/26302/5538

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a little late to the party but since I bought [Edimax EW-7811USC](http://www.edimax.com/edimax/merchandise/merchandise_detail/data/edimax/au/wireless_adapters_ac600_dual-band/ew-7811usc/) to connect the WiFi dongle to an existing antenna, I needed the 8812au.ko driver to get it working.

The procedure described in [Drivers for DWA-171 WiFi dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/26491/36891) is for an older RPI (if you use **Raspberry PI 2**), so you compile for the wrong kernel, that's why you get

> ERROR: could not insert '8812au': Exec format error.

By modifying the said procedure for the **Raspberry PI 2** you can get the dongle to work:

1. If you formatted the MicroSD card with the fresh version of Raspbian, don't forget to expand the file system and reboot:

   `sudo raspi-config`
2. Update the firmware to the newest version available:

   `sudo rpi-update
   sudo reboot`
3. Update and install dependencies:

   `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade && sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
   sudo apt-get install build-essential bc libncurses5-dev`
4. Clone raspberry linux kernel (only the newest code so less space is consumed and it's a lot faster!):

   `sudo git clone --depth=1 http://github.com/raspberrypi/linux rpi-kernel`
5. Create kernel configuration file and recompile (by using -j4 mark it compiles in little less than 2 hours!!!):

   `cd rpi-kernel
   KERNEL=kernel7
   sudo make bcm2709_defconfig
   sudo make -j4`
6. Build modules and headers:

   `sudo make modules_install
   sudo make modules_prepare
   sudo make headers_install`
7. Install and reboot:

   `sudo make zinstall clean
   sudo reboot`
8. Get driver sources (from gnab's modified version):

   `sudo git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au
   cd rtl8812au`
9. Modify the Makefile so that the drivers are compiled for the RPI (`sudo nano Makefile`):

   `CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = n
   CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI = y`
10. Compile and install:

    `sudo make -j4
    sudo make install`
11. Load the driver so you can use it right away without rebooting:

    `sudo insmod 8812au.ko`

By entering `ifconfig` the `wlan0` item should now be listed.

Answer (score 1):

I recently stumbled upon similar problems when I was trying to find a driver for my [Edimax EW-7811UTC](http://us.edimax.com/edimax/merchandise/merchandise_detail/data/edimax/us/wireless_adapters_ac600_dual-band/ew-7811utc/) which uses the same chipset as the [D-Link DWA-171](http://www.dlink.com/no/nb/home-solutions/connect/adapters/dwa-171-wireless-ac-dual-band-usb-adapter). I had to realize that while [OpenELEC](http://openelec.tv/) for instance does come with a driver for the [Edimax EW-7811UTC](http://us.edimax.com/edimax/merchandise/merchandise_detail/data/edimax/us/wireless_adapters_ac600_dual-band/ew-7811utc/) out of the box, [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) doesn’t.

I found a small tool called [rpi-source](https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/wiki) that is able to install the kernel sources used to build the kernel on your [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) image. It's supposed to work for Raspberry Pis 1 and 2 and kernels starting from version 3.10.37.

I've tested following procedure to compile and install the [rtl8812au](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au) driver on a [Raspberry Pi 2 Model B](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-2-model-b/) running [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) in different versions:

- Raspbian Jessie release 2016-05-27 using kernel version 4.4.11-v7+
- Raspbian Jessie release 2016-09-23 using kernel version 4.4.21-v7+

```sh
# install necessary software
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bc git

# download raspbian kernel sources, takes some minutes
sudo wget "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/notro/rpi-source/master/rpi-source" -O /usr/bin/rpi-source
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/rpi-source
rpi-source

# download the rtl8812au kernel driver and compile it, takes some minutes
git clone "https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au"
cd rtl8812au
sed -i 's/CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = y/CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = n/g' Makefile
sed -i 's/CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI = n/CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI = y/g' Makefile
make
# copy the driver and use it
sudo cp 8812au.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/wireless
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe 8812au

# check wlan0 interface appeared
ifconfig
iwconfig
```

I also created an [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/index.html) role called [raspbian-rtl8812au](https://github.com/layereight/raspbian-rtl8812au) you can use to automate the driver setup in an [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/index.html) playbook.